# How can I type the symbol for usual topology $R_{(-)}$ in LaTex?

Tags: symbols, code

How could I type the symbol as shown in the picture below?

I tried to use `$\mathbb{R}_{(-)}$` instead, but the `-` inside can not touch the parenthesis on both sides.

I want to create a horizontal line that stops automatically when it touches the parenthesis.

[image]

Comment: Off topic: I never seen such symbol for usual topology on real line.

Comment: More off-topic: perhaps that's a useful notation when used in conjunction with its counterpart having square brackets instead of round parentheses, so as to denote the "extended real line", that is, the two-point compactification of the real line. Otherwise, for the extended real line, one would have to adorn `\mathbb[R}` with an overbar, tilde, or asterisk, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about `\leftfree \mkern -12mu \rightfree` from MnSymbol package?

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathbb{R}_{\leftfree\mkern -12mu\rightfree} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. I would also like to know how to type the symbol $\mathbb{R}_{[-]}$ as well.

Comment: @Howardli621, I'm looking for such squared symbol but maybe there is no one.

Comment: @Sigur Usual *caveat*: using `MnSymbol` changes ***all*** mathematical symbols.

Comment: @egreg, yes, well remembered. I don't know how to load a single glyph but I know it is possible... and I know you know it :-)

Answer (score 26):

Sigur's answer might be appealing, but it has a big defect: with `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` you change ***every*** math symbol in your document to shapes that are thought to accompany Minion.

Besides, I find the strokes in MnSymbol to be too heavy. Your symbol should be as less intrusive as possible. How to use `MnSymbol` without all these defects?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

% from MnSymbol.sty
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[0.7] MnSymbolA5
   <6-7>  s*[0.7] MnSymbolA6
   <7-8>  s*[0.7] MnSymbolA7
   <8-9>  s*[0.7] MnSymbolA8
   <9-10> s*[0.7] MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> s*[0.7] MnSymbolA10
  <12->   s*[0.7] MnSymbolA12}{}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\usual}{%
  \text{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}\ooalign{\char"80\cr\char"82\cr}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{R}_{\usual}$

\end{document}
```

Explanation: `MnSymbol` tells us that the required symbols are from `MnSyA` that's defined as a math symbol font in the package itself. So it's easy to borrow the font definitions and adding a scale factor to make the glyph smaller.

The font table reveals that the two symbols are at positions `"80` and `"82` respectively, so we can use them in `\ooalign` that superimposes them inside `\text`, without wasting a math font family.

[image]

Comment: @Sigur `\ooalign` is a low level construct using alignments where rows must be terminated by `\cr`. This is essentially the same as `\makebox[0pt][l]{\char"80}\char"82`

Comment: Oh, thanks. Now it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 15):

Another possibility, cutting out the parenthesis from a `\bigcirc` to get more round symbols. To get a more similar symbols with square brackets, I cut them out of `amssymb`'s `\square`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\newcommand{\leftparen}{\clipbox{0 0 5.5pt 0}{\(\scriptstyle\bigcirc\)}}
\newcommand{\rightparen}{\clipbox{5.5pt 0 0 0}{\(\scriptstyle\bigcirc\)}}
\newcommand{\leftsquare}{\raisebox{-.9pt}{\clipbox{0 0 4.5pt 0}{\(\scriptstyle\square\)}}}
\newcommand{\rightsquare}{\raisebox{-.9pt}{\clipbox{4.5pt 0 0 0}{\(\scriptstyle\square\)}}}
\newcommand{\leftrightopen}{\mathrlap{\leftparen}-\!\!-\mathllap{\rightparen}}
\newcommand{\leftrightclosed}{\mathrlap{\leftsquare}-\!\!-\mathllap{\rightsquare}}
\newcommand{\Rtopopen}{\mathbb{R}_{\leftrightopen}}
\newcommand{\Rtopoclosed}{\mathbb{R}_{\leftrightclosed}}
\begin{document}
\( \Rtopopen \qquad \Rtopoclosed \)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just because a `tikz` answer is always required ... Here is one using the `Arc Barb` arrowhead style of the `arrows.meta` library.

**EDIT** Added a `line cap=round` option to show that you can pretty much customize the shape as you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\topo}{%
    {\tikz {
        \draw[<->,>={Arc Barb[length=0.15em,width=1ex]}] (0,0) -- (0.7em,0); 
    }}%
}
\newcommand{\toporound}{%
    {\tikz {
        \draw[<->,>={Arc Barb[length=0.15em,width=1ex,line cap=round]}] (0,0) -- (0.7em,0); 
    }}%
}

\begin{document}
    $ \mathbb{R}_\topo$ $ \mathbb{R}_\toporound$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `[0]`?

Comment: @Sigur Actually, I guess I got used to do it this way for macros that do not take any input argument. Is it particlarly wrong ?

Comment: If there is no argument, simply don't write anything: `\newcommand{\foo}{faa}`.

Comment: @Sigur Ok, but does it make any difference ?

Comment: Not visually, but theoretically.

Comment: @Sigur Haha, I see... I will apply your advice next time !

Comment: Very good all....upvoted to all users.

Answer (score 10):

Here are two possibilities.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \mathbb macro
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{R}_{( \mkern-6mu -\mkern-6mu )}$ or
$\mathbb{R}_{\scriptscriptstyle( \mkern-6mu -\mkern-6mu )}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, I taught a lecture course (not in mathematics!) at HKUST in early January...

Answer (score 4):

My idea is very simple...but strangely my command `\mousse` works :-))) ...using `xy` package :-) and not with sharp arrows. Obviously you can increase the length of the vector with round brackets with the parameter `.7pc`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\newcommand{\mousse}{\mkern-11mu\xymatrix@C=.7pc{
\ar@{(-)}[r]& 
}}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{R}_{\mousse}\!\! \simeq \mathbb{C}_{\mousse}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

*PS: It is not perfect like the other answers.*

**ADDENDUM:**

A different style using `scalerel` package with `\ttop` command a bit little - parameter `.7` - `\scaleobj{.7}{}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand{\ttop}{\mkern-8mu\scaleobj{.7}{\xymatrix@C=.7pc{
\ar@{(-)}[r]& 
}}}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{R}_{\ttop}\!\! \simeq \mathbb{C}_{\ttop}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a relatively simple solution using `mathllap` and manual kerning. Please Be aware that the parenthesis characters have a varying line width.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
    $\mathbb{R}_{\mathrlap{(}\mkern0.5mu \relbar \mkern-10mu \relbar \mkern0.5mu \mathllap{)}}$
    $\mathbb{R}_{\mathrlap{[}\mkern0.5mu \relbar \mkern-10mu \relbar \mkern0.5mu \mathllap{]}}$
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Very nice also this solution.